# Using chrome devtools with browsersync & --inspect

Tags: javascript, node.js, debugging, gulp, google-chrome-devtools

I can't for the life of me workout how to use the new `--inspect` with browser-sync

```
gulp.task('browser-sync', ['nodemon'], function () {
    browserSync({
        proxy: 'localhost:17230',
        port: 5000,
        notify: true,
        debug: true
    });
});
```

I have tried debug true, but this does nothing either :(

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue a few months back. You may use `nodeArgs` in order to use pass the appropriate parameters to node binary, alternatively, the `exec` option will work too.

```
const nodemon = require('gulp-nodemon');
const browserSync = require('browser-sync');

gulp.task('browser-sync', ['nodemon'], function () {
    browserSync({
        proxy: 'localhost:17230',
        port: 5000,
        notify: true,
        debug: true
    });
});

gulp.task('nodemon', function() {
  let started = false;
  nodemon({
    nodeArgs: ['--inspect=0.0.0.0:17230'], // localhost + port
    // You may also use {exec: 'node --inspect'}
    ext: 'js',
    ignore: ['.idea/*', 'node_modules/*'],
    script: 'server.js',
    tasks: ['lint'],
    verbose: true
    delay: 2000
  })
  .on('start', () => {
    // to avoid nodemon being started multiple times
    if (!started) {
      setTimeout(() => done(), 100);
      started = true;
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, Theodore.  I tried awarding you the bounty, but it says I have to wait a couple of hours.

Comment: Cheers mate, just a quick note though. I had really hard times using gulp before switching to `npm scripts`, give them a try.